# How to get all files in a ZipEntry's subdirectory?

Tags: java, zip, war

Imagine I have a zip file `warfile` and a subdirectory `.ebextensions` inside that file.

```
final ZipFile warfile = new ZipFile(...);
final ZipEntry ebextdir = warfile.getEntry(".ebextensions");
```

How can I get all files (name and contents) inside the `.ebextensions` directory?

Is there a better way than traversing the `warfile.entries()` result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interate trhough all entries in ZipFile and get all files that are in a specified directory (name starts with directory name):

```
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("archive.zip");
Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> e = zipFile.entries();
while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
  ZipEntry entry = e.nextElement();
  if (entry.getName().startswit(".ebextensions/") && ! entry.isDirectory()) {
    // procss file 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know a method without traversing all files?